# Cannot see my graph on JanusGraph Server with BerkeleyDB storage from .NET client

Tags: c#, .net, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

Can someone help me to understand why I don't see the graph from JanusGraph.Net client?

I'm running the latest [Docker image](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker/blob/master/0.5/Dockerfile) for JanusGraph from Docker Hub. After connecting to the JanusGraph using the built-in console I created a sample Graph of the Gods and was able to query it using the following commands:

```rb
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/janusgraph-berkeleyje-lucene.properties')
GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(graph)
g = graph.traversal()
g.V().count()
```

Because the graph remained across container restarts (was able to query it again **without** `GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(graph)` command) and some files were created inside the `/opt/janusgraph/db/berkeley/` folder I assume that everything works.

Then I updated the `graphs.graph` property of the `/opt/janusgraph/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml` (path taken from [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker/blob/df787801e910424ca5f9a04eb8d22e09fee0bfd0/0.5/docker-entrypoint.sh#L82)) to this value:

```
graphs: {
  graph: conf/janusgraph-berkeleyje-lucene.properties
}
```

and restarted container.

After that I created a simple .NET console application using [JanusGraph.Net](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-dotnet) from  with the following code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = JanusGraphClientBuilder
       .BuildClientForServer(new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182))
       .Create();

    var g = AnonymousTraversalSource
       .Traversal()
       .WithRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(client));

    var count = g.V().Count().Next();
}
```

and the `count` variable is always zero. It looks like that my .NET application connected to some another (probably in-memory) empty graph on this server.

What else should I change or update? Please help to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it was not very obvious, but JanusGraph Docker image is pre-configured to use BerkeleyDB by default (BTW according to the [documentation](https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/server/) it should be Cassandra). I found it taking a look at the Gremlin Server logs. Gremlin Server is configured to use `/etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph.properties` on startup. This file contains a completely different configuration for BerkeleyDB than, for example, `conf/janusgraph-berkeleyje.properties` - different folders, etc. That is why my .NET application hasn't seen any data - it was connected (through Gremlin Server) to the different BerkeleyDB database.

I also wasn't able to load this file to the Gremlin console via `graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('/etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph.properties')` - got access issues. After I copied this file to the `conf` directory (and changed the access rights) - I got another error: `Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager` probably because the BerkeleyDB already exists.

So the only way I've figured out how to connect to the existing database via the Gremlin Console is to use the `:remote connect` command. I was able to load a sample "Graph of the Gods" database and later access it from my .NET application using the following commands:

```rb
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
:> GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(graph)
:> g.V().count()
==>12
```

Comment: Is there guidance somewhere on why this docker image has two folders of JanusGraph and Gremlin configuration settings? Why is there /etc/opt with property files and /etc/opt/janusgraph/conf with overriding and additional ones?